# How to setup Joomla with multiple languages all under the same menu

Tags: multilingual

I want a bilingual website and I want all articles, regardless of their language to be in the same article listing (menu).

For example, I create a french article in the blog category, and an english article in the blog category also. None of these articles are translated, they are both distinct individual articles.

When someone clicks "blog" on my menu, I want them to see a listing of articles, which contains BOTH articles regardless of their language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you create an article simply tag the language of your article to "All"[image: screenshot]

Comment: Technically, that is the correct answer to my question. But it leaves me with a new problem. I wanted to a: have the language associated to the article in the metadata so I could b: use that to add a css "badge" for french articles.

Comment: you can use tag or note for that with combination of template override